# Count the occuarences of each elements in numpy array, where elements are elementwise equal with another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, count

I have two arrays like
`[2,2,0,1,1,1,2]` and `[2,2,0,1,1,1,0]`
I need to count (eg. with bincount) the occourances of each element in the first array, where the elements equal by position in the second array.
So in this case, we get `[1,3,2]`, because 0 occurs once in the same position of the arrays, 1 occurs three times in the same positions and 2 occurs twice in the same positions.
I tried this, but not the desired result:
`np.bincount(a[a==b])`
Can someone help me?

Comment: I tried `np.bincount(a[a==b])` and it works. Maybe there are some typos in your code?

Comment: Ironically `np.bincount(a[a==b])` is what I tried to get the desired result until I read the last line that said it doesn't work. We seem to be either lacking information or it's a typo.

Comment: It is working, but if the elements at the end are zeros, it shrinks them, so the array is shorter than the original one.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what bincount does. The size of the output will have a length equal to `max(set(a)) + 1`, where `a` is an iterable with only elements of interests. It bears no relation to the size of `a` itself, but the highest value in `a`.

Comment: "*I tried this, but not the desired result:*" Can you tell us what the desired result is? Because earlier you implied it's `[1,3,2]` and I can't reconcile your statements.

Comment: For clarity's sake, display `a[a==b]`, and tell us whether that's what you expect, and how `bincount` should treat it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put your lists in np array format:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2,2,0,1,1,1,2])
b = np.array([2,2,0,1,1,1,0])

np.bincount(a, weights=(a==b)) # [1, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datatable import dt, f, by

df = dt.Frame(
    col1=[2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2],
    col2=[2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
)

df['equal'] = dt.ifelse(f.col1 == f.col2, 1, 0)

df_sub = df[:, {"sum": dt.sum(f.equal)}, by('col1')]

yourlist = df_sub['sum'].to_list()[0]

yourlist

[1, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_1 = np.array([2,2,0,1,1,1,2])
array_2 = np.array([2,2,0,1,1,1,0])

# set up a bins array for the results:
if array_1.max() > array_2.max():
    bins = np.zeros(array_1.max()+1)
else:
    bins = np.zeros(array_2.max()+1)

# fill the bin values:
for val1, val2 in zip(array_1, array_2):
    if val1 == val2:
        bins[val1] += 1

# convert bins to a list with int values
bins = bins.astype(int).tolist()
```

And the results:

```
[1, 3, 2]
```